# Text not centered after adding an image on button using ::before

Tags: javascript, html

Text on the button were in the middle, when i added an image using `::before` then the text went up alittle and the button moved down alittle, how would i centre the text back [image: Here's an image]

```css
.container{
    text-align:center;
}
.btn{
    width:200px;
    height:55px;
    /*width:195px;
    height:50px;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn1{
    border: #00baaf;
    background: #00baaf;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
}
.btn1::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands-vol-2/512/discord-512.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn1">Add to server</button>
```

Comment: Please can you create a [mcve]

Comment: Just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex with center layout, give it a try

```
.btn1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't fix it, i edited the question with more code if you can please check again

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
    text-align:center;
}
.btn{
    width:200px;
    height:55px;
    /*width:195px;
    height:50px;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn1{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: #00baaf;
    background: #00baaf;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
}
.btn1::before {
    content: "";
    background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands-vol-2/512/discord-512.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn1">Add to server</button>
```

Comment: You should explain what you did to make a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```css
.btn1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: #00baaf;
  background: #00baaf;
  color: white;
  margin:10px;
}

.btn1::before {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands-vol-2/512/discord-512.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Just replace the style for `.btn1` and `.btn1::before`

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer using absolute positioning instead of floating. It's more stable and easy to understand.

```css
.container{
    text-align:center;
}
.btn{
    width:200px;
    height:55px;
    /*width:195px;
    height:50px;*/
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.btn1{
    border: #00baaf;
    background: #00baaf;
    color: white;
    margin:10px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn1::before {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10px;
    content: "";
    background: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands-vol-2/512/discord-512.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn1">Add to server</button>
```